# Chef Lint Warning reported by foodcritic

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I configured a Jenkins job to run foodcritic's analysis as was recomended by [official site](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/).
When i run this job, all results was presented as follow:

[image: foodcritic report on jenkins]

As show the previous table, the code base have a "Chef List Warning" referenced by [official site](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/) as [FC017](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/#FC017). The original code for postgredb.rb it is:

```
# Support whyrun
require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'

require 'chef/mixin/language'
include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut

def whyrun_supported?
   true
end

action :install do
  version = @new_resource.version
  options = @new_resource.options
  e = execute "sudo apt-get install postgresql-#{version} #{options}"
  @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(e.updated_by_last_action?)
end

# Now, it just changes the default password to postgres.
action :unistall do
  converge_by "Unistall postgresql--#{@new_resource.version}" do
     e = execute "sudo apt-get purge postgresql--#{@new_resource.version}" do
       #not_if { "dpkg --get-selections | grep postgresql-#{@new_resource.version}" }
     end
  end
end

...
```

The [FC017](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/#FC017) warning was for line 10 because "LWRP does not notify when updated occur":

```
 @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(e.updated_by_last_action?)
```

Then I try to solve problem changing line for this:

```
 @new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
```

But this problem persisted on line 10.

Does anyone know what is the problem? why this warning don't was eliminated if parameter it's set to be true?

Comment: have you tried to remove the @ symbol from before new_resource?

Comment: thanks punkle, your suggestion solved the warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `@` symbol from before `new_resource`